# operate over each column of data frame and return

Tags: r

`tmp` is a dataframe and I need to clean each of the columns in it.

I used:

```
 cleandata <- sapply(tmp, clean)
```

But I see that it does not return a dataframe but a list.

My clean function looks like this:

```
clean <- function(col){
 gsub("[\r\n]", " ...REPLACED........", col)
  }
```

How do I get my dataframe back with clean columns ?

Snapshot of data in tmp:

```
 [28,] "fcgh@fghv.com" FALSE        FALSE 1000062780     
 [29,] List,0                       FALSE        FALSE 1000062780     
 [30,] Character,12                 FALSE        FALSE 1000062780     
 [31,] List,0                       FALSE        FALSE 1000062780     
 [32,] List,0                       FALSE        FALSE 1000062780     
 [33,] List,0                       FALSE        FALSE 1000062780
```

There are ofcourse more rows and columns but looks something like above.

Comment: It is better to use `lapply` and then do `do.call(cbind, lapply(tmp, clean))`

Comment: @Cath: Updated...

Comment: You have a `list` in 'tmp'.  Please show the example data using `dput`

Comment: @akrun: changing cbind to rbind in your solution worked. could you please explain the difference?

Comment: The difference is that `sapply` is by default `simplify = TRUE` so if you don't specify `simplify=FALSE`, it can coerce to matrix or vector depending on the dimension of the list elements.  With `lapply`, we always return a `list` so we know what we expecte